# Eth node quiknode and infura question

Tags: nodes

1. For infura node, whether the API support send transaction or support sending ERC20 token(this is calling contract actually)? supprt creating accounts also?
2. For Quiknode, whether the API will support creating accounts and send traction? even sending erc20 token? How to set to port? 8545?
3. What is the difference for geth node and parity node? Infura is what kind of node?

Answer (score 1):

QuikNode does not support the `personal` module on either Geth or Parity.

This is for security, as online nodes should not hold wallet or key information.

You can still send signed transactions via the eth_sendRawTransaction call (https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC#eth_sendrawtransaction).

For more information on ETH wallet/account best practices, check out "https://pastebin.com/1qJPMP74" (on using `ethers` Ethereum wallet library).

You shouldn't need to set port when using the RPC URL, but if you need to `443` should work.

Check out the QuikStart guides in the UI for examples on how to integrate QuikNode into your app: [image: QuikNode Guides]

Further reading on Key Management on QuikNode blog: https://blog.quiknode.io/key-management-ux-and-security/

Answer (score 0):

**1**

**whether the API support send transaction or support sending ERC20 token:** 
yes: https://infura.io/docs/ethereum/json-rpc/eth_sendRawTransaction

**this is calling contract actually)?:**

yes

**supprt creating accounts also :**

No, this is not something you do on chain.

**2**

No for creating accounts. You don't "create" an account on blockchain, you actually claim an address and its private key based on an algorithm.

Yes you can send transaction. An ERC20 token is a smart contract. Please read documentation about smart contracts.

**3**

Difference between geth and parity: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/62655/20808

It tooks me 5 minutes to find these information. Please make your own research first.